# Defining XML fields to be displayed in a datagrid through a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datagrid, dataset

The following code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet;
ds.ReadXml("c:\output\" + nome);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

succeeds in getting the fields from the XML, but as default it only displays the three first fields
(this XML specially may have about 60 fields, of which i wish to gather 3 or 4 of them)

how do i take off these fields and choose the fields that i want?

facts:
i know the names of the fields
i have unlimited space for the xml datagrid display
i don't need links or anything, just normal display of data
i'd like to know aso if there's a way of loading more than one xml into a datagrid (several rows)
answer either in c# or vb.net.. there's no problem

Comment: Assuming you want a view only app... In the GUI designer, add just the columns you're interested in.  Open the DataSet as normal, whip through the DataTable entries (likely only 1 in your case) and iterate over each row extracting only the columns you're interested in...

Comment: what if i want to load more than one xml into a datagrid ? like each row for one xml file and 3 or 4 columns as fields ? is there a way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it.
Used data table as the binding.
in each column i chose the desired field and then in each row creating routine i got the data from the dataset just like i would normally:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim dr As Data.DataRow = Nothing
```

(... column creating...)

```
dr(0) = ds.Tables("<xml table>").Rows(0)("xml field>")
...
...
```

after everything, i just bind it to a gridview:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Thank you.